# Give a scalar equation for a plane at distance 6 from the plane P with equation: -2x + y + 2z = 5.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]
Give a scalar equation for a plane at distance $6$ from the plane P with equation
$$
-2x + y + 2z = 5
$$

AFAIK, the two planes should be parallel, resulting in their normal vectors being the same, but I'm not sure where to proceed from there. What should my next step be $?$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Take a point on your plane and find another point six units away along the normal vector. Then use the new point and your normal vector to construct the new plane.

Comment: @JohnDouma If I add 6 to, say, the X value of the point on my plane, would that be a point 6 six units away along the normal vector?

Comment: @Sand No. The distance from a plane is along a perpendicular line. The equation of your plane gives you the normal vector. Divide that vector by its magnitude to get a unit vector in that direction and then multiply that unit vector by $6$. Add that vector to a point on your plane to get a point on the new plane. Then the new point along with the original normal vector gives you your new plane.

Comment: @JohnDouma Are Felix Marin's two solutions below, the only solutions? If I'm not mistaken, there should be many different solutions, since an arbitrary point on the plane is chosen.

Comment: @Sand I haven't read that but there can be only two planes that distance away because the planes must be parallel. A non-parallel plane would intersect your plane so it would be a distance of zero away. Note that you can express the same plane more than one way, e.g. $x+y+z=1$ is the same plane as $2x+2y+2z=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The given plane $\ds{\bf P_{g}}$ is described by $\ds{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n} = 5}$ where $\ds{\vec{n} \equiv -2\,\hat{x} + \hat{y} +2\,\hat{z}}$.
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\bullet & \mbox{Choose any point}\ \in\ {\bf P_{g}}\mbox{. For instance,}\ \ds{5\,\hat{y}}.
\\
\bullet & \mbox{The other plane}\ \ds{\bf P_{o}}\ \mbox{has the equation}\ \ds{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n} = a}.
\\ \bullet & \mbox{Minimize}\ \ds{\pars{\vec{r} - 5\,\hat{y}}^{2} = \vec{r}\cdot\vec{r} -10\hat{y}\cdot\vec{r} + 25}  
\end{array}\right.
$$
Namely,
\begin{align*}
0 & = \delta\bracks{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r} -10\hat{y}\cdot\vec{r} + 25 - 2\lambda\pars{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n} -a}} =
\delta\vec{r}\cdot\bracks{2\vec{r} -10\,\hat{y} - 2\lambda\vec{n}}
\\[5mm]  & \implies \vec{r} = 5\,\hat{y} + \lambda\vec{n} \implies
a = \vec{r}\cdot\vec{n} = 5 + 9\lambda \implies \lambda = {a - 5 \over 9}
\\[5mm] & \implies \vec{r} = 5\,\hat{y} + {a - 5 \over 9}\vec{n}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Moreover,}\ 6 = \verts{\vec{r} - \vec{y}} =
\verts{4\,\hat{y} + {a - 5 \over 9}\vec{n}} \
\\[5mm] & =
\root{16 + {\pars{a - 5}^{2} \over 9} + 8\,{a - 5 \over 9}} \implies
a = -13\quad\mbox{or}\quad a = 15
\end{align*}
$$
\mbox{Solutions:}
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\left\{\begin{array}{crcrcrcr}
\bullet & \ds{-2\,\hat{x}} & \ds{+} & \ds{\hat{y}} & \ds{+} & \ds{2\,\hat{z}} & \ds{=} & \ds{-13}
\\[2mm]
\bullet & \ds{-2\,\hat{x}} & \ds{+} & \ds{\hat{y}} & \ds{+} & \ds{2\,\hat{z}} & \ds{=} & \ds{15}
\end{array}\right.}} \\
$$